# Is it possible to pass control back to browser after plugin is loaded

Tags: c, plugins, browser, network-programming, npapi

I have created NPAPI browser plugin. My plugin can handle certain mime-types, but i wish to give the user an option whether he wants to load the content using plugin or browser should take the default action. A Gtk dialog box with these options. But is it possible to give control back to browser after plugin is loaded.

Comment: If you want to give users that option on arbitrary pages, you could look into writing an extension/addon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to undo the handoff of content to a plugin, no.

Is this embedded content, or content loaded directly in its own tab? If it's the former, you could use JS to decide whether or not to create the plugin object in the first place. If it's the latter, and you control how the user gets to the content, you could give them a choice and then serve the content two different ways, one with the default type (which you wouldn't register your plugin for), and one with a special type your plugin handles.

Comment: actually i want to give the option to user after the plugin is loaded, the gtk dialog is created by plugin itself, so if user doesn't wish to use plugin, the plugin should give control back to browser, and let browser handle that. something like response->browser->plugin->browser

Comment: I understand what you want to do, and as I said that's not possible. I was suggesting other ways that *would* work that you might be able to get a similar effect.